# Displaying input values of a form in a table using angularJs

Tags: angularjs, html-table

I have a form to input the name and then when I click the submit button the input value should be displayed in the table. please find the below code that I wrote.

model.html

```
<html>
<body ng-controller="myController">
<form ng-submit="addRow()">
<input type="text" ng-model="name"/>
<input type="submit" value="value"/> 
<form/>

<table>
<tr ng-repeat="record in records">
<td>{ {record.name} }<td/>
<tr/>
<table/>
<body/>
<html/>
```

script.js

```
myApp.controller('testController,[$scope',function($scope)
{
$scope.records=[];
$scope.addRow = function()
{
$scope.records.push({'name': $scope.name});
};
}]);
```

But the output table cell shows as { {record.name} }. I want to print the name which I am typing in the text box

Answer (score 0):

make sure to fix the following :

- add ng-app directive to your html and define your module in the js.
- controller name is different on your html from what you have in you javascript

  - please make sure to close your quotations for 'testController' in js and '$scope' variables.

here is a working jsFiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/wasef89/5dnfh4yt/10/) 
html :

```
  <body ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="testController">
    <form ng-submit="addRow()">
      <input type="text" ng-model="name" />
      <input type="submit" value="value" />
      <form/>

      <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="record in records">
          <td>{{record.name}} <td/>
         <tr/>
       <table/>
   <body/>
<html/>
```

javsacript

```
myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('testController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.records = [];
  $scope.addRow = function() {
    $scope.records.push({
      'name': $scope.name
    });
  };
}]);
```